# Что-то не то с переводом бана

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[Встретил](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/12123/vadizar) такой текст:

> Учётная запись [временно заблокирована](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), для маркетингового контента. Дата окончания блокировки: через 7 дней.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что за *"для маркетингового контента"?* Возможно "за", а не "для"? Но всё равно какая-то мутная формулировка получается. Давайте поменяем?

Comment: Николас уже менял: [поправил](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34565175#34565175)

Comment: @Grundy, а на что?)

Comment: [Вот так вышло «за размещение рекламных материалов»](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34565195#34565195)

Comment: @Grundy А почему эффекта нету, если Николас уже поменял?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov [тынц](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/385/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d1%81-transifex-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82#comment945_385)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оригинальная строка в движке выглядит так:

> This account is $linkStart$temporarily suspended$linkEnd$$reason$. The suspension period ends $penaltyEndDate$.

Перевод в transifex так:

> Учётная запись $linkStart$временно заблокирована,$linkEnd$$reason$. Дата окончания блокировки: $penaltyEndDate$.

Переменная `$reason$` в данном случае будет разворачиваться в:

> за размещение рекламных материалов

В оригинале:

> for promotional content

Но здесь всё равно присутствуют 2 проблемы:

1. Запятая (т.к. по правилам русского языка она тут не нужна)
2. Снова запятая (но в этот раз из-за того, что на Мете причина не указывается, т.е. `$reason$` становится пустой строкой, и текст выглядит так:

   > [image: мета]

Причины блокировки могут быть разные (надо уточнить у разработчиков, или хотя бы модераторов), мне в transifex удалось найти следующие фразы:

- за нарушения при голосовании / for voting irregularities
- за нарушение правил / for rule violations
- за плагиат / for plagiarism
- за размещение рекламных материалов / for promotional content
- чтобы задавать вопросы по программированию  на Мете / for asking programming questions on meta // **здесь что-то не так**
- чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться / to cool down
- из-за низкого качества участия пользователя / because of low-quality contributions

Т.о. запятую можно было бы перенести в текст причины блокировки, если там действительно предполагается запятая, например для `чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться`.

Comment: _чтобы задавать вопросы по программированию на Мете / for asking programming questions on meta // **здесь что-то не так**_ Возможно, будет лучше "за размещение вопросов по программированию на Мете"? ну или "за публикацию вопросов ..."

Comment: @Akina так и будет, я думаю.