# Когда можно звать модератора тревогой

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация

Понятно, что модератора надо звать тревогой на спам, ругань и на прочее, требующее как можно более оперативной реакции, действие. Но иногда для нужд развития сообщества, например, нужно получить информацию именно от лица власть имущих. Разумно ли в таких случаях помечать сообщения фиктивными тревогами? В частности, в чате иногда хочется пингануть любого из модераторов, не важно кого. Как это лучше сделать - через тревогу или обычное упоминание всех ников? При этом достаточно получить ответ от любого из модераторов. И "тревога" тут кажется наиболее простым способом, если конечно верна моя гипотеза о том, что тревога видна (как уведомление) только первому, отреагировавшему на нее, модератору.

Пример: в [сообщении о возможных причинах бана](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4464/176217) нужна реакция от модератора, для улучшения качества локализации. Нужно как-то привлечь внимание модератора.

Хотелось бы услышать ответы именно от действующих модераторов, так как в случае чего, им же и придется реагировать :)

Comment: если срочно - чат (я увижу уведомление на телефоне). если несрочно - тревога (попадет в рыжую очередь, точно не потеряется).

Comment: @Nofate чат, т.е. через собаку и ник? Просто в чате тоже можно флагнуть. Скажем так: мне не важно, кто среагирует, это не сверхсрочно, но ответ нужен исключительно от модератора. Я предполагал, что если один из модераторов тревогу обработал, другие ее не увидят. Это так?

Comment: @alexolut Тревоги в чате видят все модераторы Stack Exchange (в том числе и те, кто не знает русский язык)!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky будет стимул к изучению :)

Answer (score 2):

> Понятно, что модератора надо звать тревогой на спам, ругань и на прочее, требующее как можно более оперативной реакции, действие.

Наоборот же, для этого уже есть готовая тревога, не требующая модераторов.

> Разумно ли в таких случаях помечать сообщения фиктивными тревогами?

Непонятно, по какому принципу должно выбираться сообщение для тревоги.

> Как это лучше сделать - через тревогу или обычное упоминание всех ников?

Вроде чат выглядит гораздо лучше. Плюс, там смогут другие прочитать, если понадобится.

> Хотелось бы услышать ответы именно от действующих модераторов

Ну посмотрим, но вообще вопрос какой-то странный и слишком размытый.

Comment: как правило, *готовые тревоги на ругань* модераторы разгребают руками

Comment: @Nofate, там же -6 и удаление духом?

Comment: редко доходит до этого.

Comment: @Nofate, но ставить тревогу модератору вместо тревоги спама нелогично же?

Comment: я и не агитирую

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: Тревога по спаму до модератора не доходит разве?

Comment: @alexolut, доходит.

Comment: @Nofate ну вот тогда не понятны мне доводы Qwertiy

Comment: @alexolut, мне тоже

Comment: @alexolut не просто доходит, а еще и падает в отдельную категорию с красной подсветкой.

Comment: @PashaPash дайте же уже ответ! :)